# How to fix paddings in email layout?

Tags: html, css, layout, html-email

I have a problem with email layout paddings on mobile version. I think td tag add their padding without permit, and i can't fix it. Maybe you have ideas guys?
desktop version:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TwDJ4.png)
mobile version:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Odiy.png)
code of these block:

```
 <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="margin:0; padding:0;">
                                                <tr style="margin:0; padding:0;">
                                                    <td class="link-td">
                                                        <a class="link" href="#" style="font-size: 11px;color: #08D2FF;font-weight: 600;text-decoration: none;margin: 0;margin-bottom: 5px;padding: 0;">dawcdawdcawdc</a>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </table>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="margin:0; padding:0;">
                                                <tr style="margin:0; padding:0;">
                                                    <td class="link-td">
                                                        <a class="link" href="#" style="font-size: 11px;color: #08D2FF;font-weight: 600;text-decoration: none;margin: 0;margin-bottom: 5px;padding: 0;">awdcawdcawd</a>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </table>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="margin:0; padding:0;">
                                                <tr style="margin:0; padding:0;">
                                                    <td class="link-td">
                                                        <a class="link" href="#" style="font-size: 11px;color: #08D2FF;font-weight: 600;text-decoration: none;margin: 0;margin-bottom: 5px;padding: 0;">acdawcdawdcaw</a>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </table>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="margin:0; padding:0;">
                                                <tr style="margin:0; padding:0;">
                                                    <td>
                                                        <p style="font-size: 11px;color: #08D2FF;font-weight: 600;text-decoration: none;margin: 0;margin-bottom: 5px;padding: 0;">acdawdcawdcw</p>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </table>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
```

I have tried give td tag, link class padding: 0; margin:0; line-height: 100%, and that don't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step three of [this article](https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/build-an-html-email-template-from-scratch--webdesign-12770) suggests that you should be setting `padding:0;` on your `<td>` elements, whereas you are only setting this on `<tr>` and `<a>`.

And do you really need nested tables? Simplifying your code to use a single table may be helpful as well.

Comment: Thank you! I simplified the structure a bit and realized the error